# Postfix Virtual Domain - mail is send by second server

Tags: postfix, virtualization, domain, block

i setup postfix on a VPS with two domains (each one with own ip)

domain1 - 194.xxx.xxx.1

domain2 - 194.xxx.xxx.2

when i send a mail via domain2 - i am getting dmarc reports that the mail uses the mailserver from domain1. And the mail is blocked.

i have no idea why this happend ... the header of the mails looks like this one:

```
Return-Path 
X-Spam-Checker-Version SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on server1.domain1.com
X-Spam-Level 
X-Spam-Status No, score=0.0 required=5.0 tests=NO_RELAYS,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Original-To user@domain2.com
Delivered-To user@server1.domain1.com
Received by server1.domain1.com (Postfix)
    id xyz Thu,  7 Jul 2016 164833 +0200 (CEST)
Date Thu,  7 Jul 2016 164833 +0200 (CEST)
From MAILER-DAEMON@server1.domain1.com (Mail Delivery System)
Subject Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To user@domain2.com
```

my master-cf entry:

```
194.xxx.xxx.1:submission    inet    n   -   -   -   -   smtpd
    -o myhostname=server1.domain1.com
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes 

194.xxx.xxx.2:submission    inet    n   -   -   -   -   smtpd
        -o smtp_helo_name=mail.domain2.com
        -o myhostname=mail.domain2.com
        -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt    
        -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

main.cf

```
# Disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 leaving TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 enabled.
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1

# Configure the allowed cipher list
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

# Enable EECDH key exchange for Forward Security
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade=ultra

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
myorigin = /etc/mailname
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
#myhostname = server1.domain1.com
#mydestination = server1.domain1.com, localhost.domain1.com, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

## server will announce STARTTLS ##
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes 

# TLS parameters
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# HELO parameters
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
     reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
     reject_invalid_hostname,
     permit

# 'encrypt' will enforce SSL. Not recommended for live servers ##
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
#smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt 

smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# neue restrictions 10.06.16
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_sender,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_sender_domain,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
   reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
   permit
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
# smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
relayhost = 
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
home_mailbox = Maildir/
allow_percent_hack = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# multi ip on für not resolve meldubg im log
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C RESOLV_MULTI=on
```

thankfull for any help or pointing me in the right direction !

mic

---

!!Edit!!

i send a mail to gmx.net (german freemailer) and to hotmail. 
On gmx i have this header (mail passed)

```
Return-Path: <user@domain2.com>
Received: from server1.domain1.com ([194.xxx.xxx.1]) by mx-ha.gmx.net
 (mxgmx110) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 0Llpue-1amr0r3TPM-00ZNcb for
 <mic@gmx.net>; Sat, 09 Jul 2016 18:02:49 +0200
Received: from [192.168.xxx.xxx] (cli-5b7ee90b [91.xx.xx.xx])
    by mail.domain2.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E1D9512027A
    for <mic@gmx.net>; Sat,  9 Jul 2016 18:02:47 +0200 (CEST)
To: "R.T." <mic@gmx.net>
From: User <user@domain2.com>
Subject: test666
```

As you can see the Return-Path is the correct one : domain2.com

but the first "Received: from server1.domain1.com ([194.xxx.xxx.1]) "
points to the server of domain1.com

and the second "Received: from [192.168.xxx.xxx] (cli-5b7ee90b [91.xx.xx.xx]) by mail.domain2.com (Postfix)"

comes from the right server : mail.domain2.com.

i tried everything - i checked everything - i have no idea why this heppend - i checked the header from mails of server1.domain1.com and they are all fine - this happens only when using smtp on mail.domain2.com.

and as the reports say - mail is refused because the header is from domain2 but sender&ip are from domain1

but. hotmail, yahoo, apple & google are blocking my mails from domain2.

Answer (score 0):

None of the configuration you provide relates to the issue you're getting.

Mail being rejected based on `DMARC` rules means that the `SPF` rules are not respected.  You should revise your `SPF` for both domains to include the other one so that both servers can send for both domains.

When doing `SPF` changes, it's always a good idea to loosen the `DMARC` rules so that the messages do not get rejected when they fail `SPF` validation.  That way you can monitor and troubleshoot issues with it before making it more strict.

Comment: thank you for answering - i changed my SPF ifor both domains to
"v=spf1 a mx include:mail.domain2.com include:server1.domain1.com ~all"

but it is still the same. header shows that the mail from Domain2 is sended via Mailserver from Domain1

Comment: The SPF won't affect the mail header but will allow your message to go through.  About your other "problem", are you sure you're connecting to the right SMTP service?

Comment: yeah .. i just used telnet to send me a mail and got this header :

`Return-Path: <info@domain2.com>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on server1.domain1.com

X-Original-To: user@domain2.com
Delivered-To: user@server1.domain1.com
Received: from domain2.com (mail.domain2.com [194.xxx.xxx.2])
 by mail.domain2.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 5591F120468
 for <user@domain2.com>; Sat,  9 Jul 2016 16:57:03 +0200 (CEST)
Subject: testmail telnet
Message-Id: <20160709145745.5591F120468@server1.domain1.com>

From: info@domain2.com`

Comment: part of report :

`-<row>

<source_ip>194.xxx.xxx.1</source_ip>

<count>1</count>


-<policy_evaluated>

<disposition>none</disposition>

<dkim>fail</dkim>

<spf>fail</spf>

</policy_evaluated>

</row>


-<identifiers>

<header_from>domain2.com</header_from>

</identifiers>


-<auth_results>


-<dkim>

<domain>server1.domain1.com</domain>

<result>neutral</result>

</dkim>


-<spf>

<domain>server1.domain1.com</domain>

<result>none</result>

</spf>

</auth_results>

</record>

</feedback>`

Comment: I don't see a problem in there.  Perhaps what's most confusing is that you test sending an receiving on the same server.  Try to send a message to another email address from both domains and look at the headers.

Comment: i added some more information to the main topic - for better formatting - thx again for your help!

Comment: found the reason - there is a problem with the alias map. i think i setup the mailserver new .. thank you for your assistance Julie!