# postfix user unknown in virtual alias table

Tags: email, postfix, virtualization

first of all - i am still on a beginner level. As the Topic say i have problems with my mailserver (postfix 2.11.3) on Debian Jessie. It is a VPS with two domains and each has his own IP.

When i setup postfix start of this year - all seems fine - but now i am getting more and more reports that my Header isnt the same as the sender-domain.

I asked already about this on another [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/788875/postfix-virtual-domain-mail-is-send-by-second-server) but there was i looking for the wrong way and for clarity i opend a second thread.

my problem:

i think there is a mismatch with adressrewriting because when debuging SMTP i get this in mail.log:

```
 /smtpd[16553]: > cli[91.xxx.xxx.11]: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
 /smtpd[16553]: < cli[91.xxx.xxx.11]: MAIL FROM:<info@tiw.com> BODY=8BITMIME SIZE=398
 /smtpd[16553]: extract_addr: input: <info@tiw.com>
 /smtpd[16553]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: connect to subsystem private/rewrite
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr request = rewrite
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr rule = local
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr address = info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: 0
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: address
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: (end)
 /smtpd[16553]: rewrite_clnt: local: info@tiw.com -> info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr request = resolve
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr sender = 
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr address = info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: 0
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: transport
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: transport
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: error
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: nexthop
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: 5.1.1 User unknown in virtual alias table
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: recipient
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: 512
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: (end)
 /smtpd[16553]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `info@tiw.com' -> transp=`error' host=`5.1.1 User unknown in virtual alias table' rcpt=`info@tiw.com' flags= class=alias
 /smtpd[16553]: ctable_locate: install entry key info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: extract_addr: in: <info@tiw.com>, result: info@tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr request = rewrite
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr rule = local
 /smtpd[16553]: send attr address = double-bounce
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: flags
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: 0
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: address
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute value: double-bounce@server1.tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
 /smtpd[16553]: input attribute name: (end)
 /smtpd[16553]: rewrite_clnt: local: double-bounce -> double-bounce@server1.tiw.com
 /smtpd[16553]: smtpd_check_rewrite: trying: permit_inet_interfaces
 /smtpd[16553]: permit_inet_interfaces: cli 91.xxx.xxx.11
```

i have a /etc/postfix/virtual file with this user:

```
info@tiw.com    info.tiw
```

i can do the login in Thunderbird with info.tiw 
but how i read the debuglog .. he tries to rewrite info@tiw.com to info@tiw.com. There is no info@tiw.com user on the system (the user is info.tiw) and therefor it bounces or doublebounce (don´t be sure what this does - seems to send it over a kind of basic adress) it and the mail goes out.

This happen for both domains (just posted one log).

I am sorry to ask here .. but i tried today the whole day to find out how and what happend - at the end i found the problem with the "5.1.1 user not in virtual alias table" but i have really no idea how to solve this.

Please, i need some help.

postconf -n (restarted with a example conf)

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_domains = tiw.com dnoe.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: what a mess - i screw up my mail server totaly .. glad to had a backup .. please i need to rewrite 

`user@domain.com to user.domain - like
user@example.com -> user.example`

thats why i get 5.1.1. user unknown

Answer (score 5):

After long searches i found the solution :

myorigin = localhost
mydestination = localhost

solution finaly found here on server-fault - this is the [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/710618/postfix-dovecot-multiple-domains-and-multiple-linux-accounts)